# Why I am obtaining this error trying to implement an Hibernate Many To Many mapping?

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-mapping

I am working on a Spring Boot project using Spring Data Jpa in order do persist data on my PostgreSQL DB.
I am finding some difficulties with Hibernate **Many To Many** mapping. Following details of my problem. In my project tables are not created by Hibernate but I am using Hibernate defining entity classes mapping my tables.

I have these 3 DB tables:

- **portal_user** table: to store the users of a portal:

  ```
   CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public.portal_user
   (
       id bigint NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY ( INCREMENT 1 START 1 MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 9223372036854775807 CACHE 1 ),
       first_name character varying(50) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
       middle_name character varying(50) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
       surname character varying(50) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
       sex "char" NOT NULL,
       birthdate date NOT NULL,
       tex_code character varying(50) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
       e_mail character varying(50) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
       contact_number character varying(50) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
       created_at date NOT NULL,
       CONSTRAINT user_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
   )
  ```
- **user_type** table: defines the possible user types (as ADMIN, SIMPLE_USER, etc):

  ```
   CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public.user_type
   (
       id bigint NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY ( INCREMENT 1 START 1 MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 9223372036854775807 CACHE 1 ),
       type character varying(50)[] COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
       description text COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
       CONSTRAINT user_type_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
   )
  ```
- **portal_user_user_type** table: it is the **Many To Many** association table that link together the previous two tables: this because a specific user can have multiple user types and a specific user type can be associated to multiple users:

  ```
   CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public.portal_user_user_type
   (
       id bigint NOT NULL,
       portal_user_id_fk bigint NOT NULL,
       user_type_id_fk bigint NOT NULL,
       CONSTRAINT portal_user_user_type_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
       CONSTRAINT portal_user_user_type_to_portal_user FOREIGN KEY (portal_user_id_fk)
           REFERENCES public.portal_user (id) MATCH SIMPLE
           ON UPDATE NO ACTION
           ON DELETE NO ACTION,
       CONSTRAINT portal_user_user_type_to_user_type FOREIGN KEY (user_type_id_fk)
           REFERENCES public.user_type (id) MATCH SIMPLE
           ON UPDATE NO ACTION
           ON DELETE NO ACTION
   )
  ```

Ok, then I have mapped the previous 3 classes with the following entity classes:

The **User** class map the **portal_user** table:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "portal_user")
@Data
public class User implements Serializable {
     
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 5062673109048808267L;
    
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    
    @Column(name = "first_name")
    private String firstName;
    
    @Column(name = "middle_name")
    private String middleName;
    
    @Column(name = "surname")
    private String surname;
    
    @Column(name = "sex")
    private char sex;
    
    @Column(name = "birthdate")
    private Date birthdate;
    
    @Column(name = "tex_code")
    private String taxCode;
    
    @Column(name = "e_mail")
    private String eMail;
    
    @Column(name = "contact_number")
    private String contactNumber;
    
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    @Column(name = "created_at")
    private Date createdAt;
    
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "user", orphanRemoval = true)
    @JsonManagedReference
    private Set<Address> addressesList = new HashSet<>();
    
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JsonManagedReference
    private Set<User_UserType> userToUserTypeAssociation = new HashSet<>();

    public User(String firstName, String middleName, String surname, char sex, Date birthdate, String taxCode,
            String eMail, String contactNumber, Date createdAt) {
        super();
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.middleName = middleName;
        this.surname = surname;
        this.sex = sex;
        this.birthdate = birthdate;
        this.taxCode = taxCode;
        this.eMail = eMail;
        this.contactNumber = contactNumber;
        this.createdAt = createdAt;
    }
        
}
```

**NOTE-1**: this **@OneToMany** relationship is related to another use cases and worked fine (so it is not part of this problem):

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "user", orphanRemoval = true)
@JsonManagedReference
private Set<Address> addressesList = new HashSet<>();
```

**NOTE-2**: The **User** class contains this **@OneToMany** relationship that implement one side of my **Many To Many** relationship causing the problem:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JsonManagedReference
private Set<User_UserType> userToUserTypeAssociation = new HashSet<>();
```

The **User_UserType** class is the entity class mapping my Many To Many relationship.

Then I have the **UserType** entity classes mapping the previous **user_type** DB table:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user_type")
@Data
public class UserType implements Serializable {
    
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 6904959949570501298L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;
    
    @Column(name = "description")
    private String description;
    
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "userType")
    @JsonManagedReference
    private Set<User_UserType> userToUserTypeAssociation = new HashSet<>();
    

    public UserType() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
    
    public UserType(String name, String description) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
        this.description = description;
    }


}
```

**NOTE**: this class contains this **@OneToMany** relationship representing the other side of the **Many To Many** relationship that I am trying to implement.

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "userType")
@JsonManagedReference
private Set<User_UserType> userToUserTypeAssociation = new HashSet<>();
```

Then I have implemented the **User_UserType** entity class mapping the **portal_user_user_type** (my Many To Many association table):

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "portal_user_user_type")
@Data
public class User_UserType implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -1334879762781878984L;
    
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    
    @ManyToOne()
    @JoinColumn(name = "portal_user_id_fk")
    @JsonBackReference
    private User user;
    
    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_type_id_fk")
    @JsonBackReference
    private UserType userType;

    public User_UserType() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
    
    public User_UserType(User user, UserType userType) {
        super();
        this.user = user;
        this.userType = userType;
    }

}
```

**NOTE:** this class contains the two **@ManyToOne()** relationship pointing to the related **User** and **UserType** instances.

Finnally I tried to test it by a JUnit test method, this one:

```
@SpringBootTest()
@ContextConfiguration(classes = GetUserWsApplication.class)
@TestMethodOrder(OrderAnnotation.class)
public class UserRepositoryTest {
    
    @Autowired
    private UsersRepository userRepository;
    
    
    @Test
    @Order(1)
    public void testInsertUser() {
        User user = new User("Mario", null, "Rossi", 'M', new Date(), "XXX", "xxx@gmail.com", "329123456", new Date());
        
        Set<Address> addressesList = new HashSet<>();
        addressesList.add(new Address("Italy", "RM", "00100", "Via XXX 123", "near YYY", user));
        
        user.setAddressesList(addressesList);
        
        Set<UserType> userTypesList = new HashSet<>();
        UserType userType1 = new UserType("ADMIN", "Admin user type !!!");
        UserType userType2 = new UserType("USER", "Just a simple user...");
        
        userTypesList.add(userType1);
        userTypesList.add(userType2);
        
        User_UserType user_UserType1 = new User_UserType(user, userType1);
        User_UserType user_UserType2 = new User_UserType(user, userType2);
        
        Set<User_UserType> user_UserType_List = new HashSet<>();
        user_UserType_List.add(user_UserType1);
        user_UserType_List.add(user_UserType2);
        
        user.setUserToUserTypeAssociation(user_UserType_List);
        
        userRepository.save(user);
        assertTrue(true);
        
    }
    
}
```

Running this method Spring Boot start up without error messages. Running it in debug mode it arrives to the **save()** method execution where I am trying to save my **User** instance (expecting that also the defined relationship are saved: so the two created user types and the relation into my association table).

Here something strange happens. The save method seems to give me an exception (I can see it in debug mode) but I obtain no error message in my stacktrace. Following a printscreen of what I am obtaining:

[image]

As you can see it enter into the highlighter exception but running the application to the end in the stacktrace there are no error lines related to this exception. This is my entire stacktrace from the Spring Boot startup to the end:

```
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::                (v2.5.6)

2021-11-06 19:09:01.145  INFO 22688 --- [           main] c.e.u.t.R.UserRepositoryTest             : Starting UserRepositoryTest using Java 16.0.1 on ubuntu with PID 22688 (started by andrea in /home/andrea/git/get-user-ws)
2021-11-06 19:09:01.148  INFO 22688 --- [           main] c.e.u.t.R.UserRepositoryTest             : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2021-11-06 19:09:01.896  INFO 22688 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2021-11-06 19:09:01.957  INFO 22688 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 53 ms. Found 2 JPA repository interfaces.
2021-11-06 19:09:02.805  INFO 22688 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2021-11-06 19:09:02.871  INFO 22688 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.4.32.Final
2021-11-06 19:09:03.071  INFO 22688 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.2.Final}
2021-11-06 19:09:03.211  INFO 22688 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2021-11-06 19:09:03.456  INFO 22688 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2021-11-06 19:09:03.487  INFO 22688 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
2021-11-06 19:09:04.193  INFO 22688 --- [           main] org.hibernate.tuple.PojoInstantiator     : HHH000182: No default (no-argument) constructor for class: com.easydefi.users.entity.User (class must be instantiated by Interceptor)
2021-11-06 19:09:04.323  INFO 22688 --- [           main] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
2021-11-06 19:09:04.330  INFO 22688 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2021-11-06 19:09:04.553  WARN 22688 --- [           main] JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration : spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
2021-11-06 19:09:05.626  INFO 22688 --- [           main] c.e.u.t.R.UserRepositoryTest             : Started UserRepositoryTest in 4.96 seconds (JVM running for 6.304)
2021-11-06 19:11:09.255  INFO 22688 --- [ionShutdownHook] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2021-11-06 19:11:09.257  INFO 22688 --- [ionShutdownHook] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2021-11-06 19:11:09.264  INFO 22688 --- [ionShutdownHook] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
```

So what is wrong with my code? What am I missing? How can i try to fix it? And why am I not obtanining errors line in the stacktrace if this exception was thrown?

Comment: Can you add the exception type and the exception message to the post? --- Out of curiosity: is there a specific reason why you model the join table explicitly as entity?

Comment: @Turing85 as I explained in the post I have first designed the DB, then implemented the DB tables and finnally mapped these table on the entity classes.
The problem is that I obtain no error text in the stacktrace...so how can I give you the exceptiion value?

Comment: Designing the database beforehand does not imply that we have to model the join table as entity =) annotating the `Set`s in `User` and `UserType` with `@ManyToMany` (and some acompaning annotations) should be sufficient. --- You can pull the values of variables at runtime from the debugger. When the application hits the break point, you should be able to switch to the debug view and see all variables in the current frame. From there, you can access the exact type of the `Throwable`, as well as all fields (e.g. the exception message).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The id in `portal_user_user_type` should be autogenerated but is `id bigint NOT NULL`?

But `portal_user_user_type` only holds a reference to the `User` and the `UserType`. So you could easily simplify your model.

Something like:

```java
class User {
    
    @ManyToMany(cascade = { CascadeType.ALL })
    @JoinTable(
        name = "portal_user_user_type", 
        joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "portal_user_id_fk") }, 
        inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "user_type_id_fk") }
    )
    Set<UserType> userTypes;
```

Comment: Yes the ID is an autogenerated big int NOT NULL. Doing as suggested by you end in this other error related to the fact that the ID can't be NULL on my DB table: "ERROR: null value in column "id" of relation "portal_user_user_type" violates not-null constraint"

Comment: You don't need ID in portal_user_user_type with this solution

Comment: Yes I know that I can simply create a composite key including my two FK...but for some reasons I prefear to have a separate ID PK. So is it not possible to have it using this @ManyToMany annotation? Tnx

Comment: I guess you could use 
'id bigint NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY.....' without mapping it in your entity... But that's kind of useless...